# How to modify the value of a cell with a script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Good evening.
I have a table consisting of two columns, one for the product in column B, and the number in column C.
Above this table, I have 2 lines, one to choose the product and another one for the number. They serve to count the specified products.

For example, if I choose "Sac" in C3 and the number 1 in C4, in line 12 where is the line "Sac", I should have the number 2 after the calculation done
I have a code:

```
function Test() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Feuille 1');
  var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var produit = s.getRange("c3").getValue();
  var nbrOrigin = s.getRange("c4").getValue();


  for( var row = values.length -1; row >= 0; --row )
    if (values[row][1] == produit)
      if (nbrOrigin < values[row][2]) {
        Browser.msgBox(values[row][2] - nbrOrigin);

      }
      else {
        //Browser.msgBox("Supprimer la ligne");
        s.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);
      }
}
```

I try to count the product selected, unfortunately, it does not work, or rather, I can't .....
With `Browser.msgbox`, I've got the right number, but I can't change the cell in the table.

[My test page](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EZmmdV1cH-7Upq71dkG1r_2y4GutjH1xctUMgI5dZ7E/edit?usp=sharing).

Could you guide me please?

Cordially.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
s.getRange('C4').setValue(value);
```

where `value` is the value to put on the C4 cell.

Comment: Hi @Rubén, Excuse me, I have trouble explaining myself. The value in cell C4, is the value to deduce on the associated line. For example, if I choose "Sac" in C3 and the number 1 in C4, in line 12 where is the line "Sac", I should have the number 2 after the calculation done ......